# Bad vs good practice field access android

Tags: java, android

While learning some basics of coding in android (java) I came to a point where I wanted to access multiple UI fields (from xml) in different classes. I see that I can solve this by extending Activity in the relevant classes, but is this accepted coding practise?

---

```
public class Example {

    TextView textview;        

    public Example(TextView textview) {
        this.textview = textview;
    }    
}
```

---

```
public class Example extends Activity {

    TextView textview;        

    public Example() {
        this.textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.<xml id>);
    }    
}
```

---

When the number of elements increase, the second option seems more clean to me. Obviously not every class is considered an activity in itself. So if there is another way of doing this, or a preferred version please leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: The first is an example of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is looser coupled than the second. [Loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) is good in software, e.g. it makes for more testable code.

Comment: I think using Activity in 2nd option, you are misusing that class as Activity is specially designed for interacting with UI

Comment: You should not extend Activity class if the class is not being used to display the UI, you can send in the context from your activity class to access resources(if you are creating helper classes).

Comment: @SarthakMittal that is what I was looking for. If you want to post this as an answer I can tag this as resolved.

Comment: @Adrian done. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send in the context(your activity reference for your use case) as an argument in a helper class function to access the resources.

Activity class is usually extended to be displayed as part of the UI.

Or, it can be used to act as a base class for other ActivityClasses. The base class should be marked abstract to specify that it's only going to be extended by other ActivityClasses, you also don't need to mention your base class in AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no harm in re-using the pre-defined layout files. Extending an Activity just to access the layout is a very poor practice. There in comes the concept of separating your code using architectures such as MVC, MVP and MVVM. These help in writing and maintaining large code bases.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the reference of Context ( in your case Activity) in Constructor and then using reference of the context (Activity) you can access fields. You need to take care to make this reference null when you are done or else you will be holding a reference to Context Which may lead to activity leak. I would suggest you to use WeakReference of Activity and when you need it just check if contained Activity reference is not null.

2nd way is not good as your class is actually not an actual activity (you just extend to access fields) and favoring Composition is always better.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` class should not be used for purposes different from displaying UI and also it should not be created using the constructor. If you need to access resources from another class (maybe an Utility class) pass it the `Context` and use it to retrieve the resources by id.